# regex getting words between '|'

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the full words between two `'|'` characters

example string: `{{person label|Jens Addle|border=red}}`

here I would like to get the string: `Jens Addle`

I have attempted with the following:

```
(([A-Z]\w+))
```

However, this separates the result into two words and I would like to get it as a single entity.

Comment: You can use `[^\|]+` to match any length (1-infinity) matches up until the next `|` symbol. Then you can simply match the whole group: [`\{\{([^\|]+)\|([^\|]+)\|([^\|]+)\}\}`](https://regex101.com/r/bivBOW/1). ([Debuggex Explanation](https://www.debuggex.com/r/XS5Wg8SSuvHSboyy))

Comment: Maybe just [`\|([^|]+)\|`](https://regex101.com/r/xSVHJC/1) and get the contents of the 1st capture group. Maybe more specific could be `\|([A-Z][a-z]+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)*)\|`

Comment: If you clarify where you are using the regex and what code you are using, it would be easier to help you more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

This should put the value into $1.

Key is escaping the pipes, capturing what is in between and being non-greedy about it.

```
\|(.+?)\|
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your case: `/\|(.*?)\|/gm`, or without the flags `\|(.*?)\|`.

This regex matches all character between two `|` characters. (`\|` - the `|` character, `(.*?)` - match everything and capture)

[Here is the regex101 page.](https://regex101.com/r/pHYsxz/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```php
\|\K[^|]*(?=\|)
(?<=\|)[^|]*(?=\|)
```

See the [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/eYQXgO/1) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/eYQXgO/2).

*Details*:

- `(?<=\|)` - a location that is immediately preceded with a `|` char
- `\|\K` - matches a `|` char and then "forgets" it
- `[^|]*` - zero or more chars other than a `|` char
- `(?=\|)` - a location that is immediately followed with a `|` char.

Answer (score 0):

Matching 1 ore more words between the pipe chars can be done using a capture group.

Note that `[A-Z]\w+` matches at least 2 characters.

```
\|([A-Z]\w+(?: \w+)*)(?=\|)
```

- `\|` Match `|`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z]\w+` Match an uppercase char A-Z and 1+ word characters
  - `(?: \w+)*` Optionally repeat matching a space and 1+ word characters
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?=\|)` Positive lookahead, assert `|` to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7ORPN5/1).

To take the format of the example string into account, you might also make the pattern a bit more specific:

```
{{[^|]*\|([A-Z]\w+(?: \w+)*)\|[^|]*}}
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/efF2um/1).